# How to run robot test case from Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, robotframework

Can anyone please tell how we can run robot test cases from visual Studio.
On searching on google it says how to run it from Visual studio code.
But my company uses visual Studio and not visual Studio code, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Search for how to run any script from Visual Studio, then apply it to Robot Framework.

Comment: Hi Thanks, but are .robot files supported in Visual studio? Have you used it then please guide